# Is it possible to flash an Arduino Due via its RX/TX pins?

Tags: arduino, uart, firmware

I've got a BeagleBone Black (UART1) connected to an Arduino Due (RX0 / TX0) and I'm trying to upload a new firmware via bossac:

```sh
$ bossac -i --port=ttyO1 --erase --write --verify --reset --boot=1 firmware.bin
>>> No device found on ttyO1
```

Although the normal serial communication via ttyO1 works fine.

If I connect an USB cable to the programming port (which I understand is just a communication chip to convert the usb signals to UART on RX0/TX0) everything works fine.

```
$ bossac -i --port=ttyACM0 --erase --write --verify --reset --boot=1 firmware.bin

Atmel SMART device 0x285e0a60 found
Device       : ATSAM3X8
Chip ID      : 285e0a60
Version      : v1.1 Dec 15 2010 19:25:04
Address      : 524288
Pages        : 2048
Page Size    : 256 bytes
Total Size   : 512KB
Planes       : 2
Lock Regions : 32
Locked       : none
Security     : false
Boot Flash   : false
Erase flash
done in 0.032 seconds

Write 80080 bytes to flash (313 pages)
[==============================] 100% (313/313 pages)
done in 15.389 seconds

Verify 80080 bytes of flash
[==============================] 100% (313/313 pages)
Verify successful
done in 14.106 seconds
Set boot flash true
CPU reset.
```

So my question is: Is uploading a firmware even possible via the RX/TX pins? Or do I *need* to go with one of the USB ports on the Arduino Due?

Comment: Only if the firmware onboard has a UART bootloader

Comment: Are you somehow resetting the Arduino? Because when you use the USB cable, the USB to serial chip not only connects to TX and RX pins, but also to reset pin.

Comment: I tried connecting at 1200 baud to reset, but that didn't work. Pressing reset right before upload doesn't work either. Or is there any upload procedure including the ERASE button?

Comment: So I found a manual way to get this working. First you have to press ERASE a few seconds, release then press Reset and release and then start uploading with bossac. Since ERASE is not available via a pin I guess this is not possible automatically?

Comment: Did you disconnect TX and RX from the on-board USB/serial converter before connecting your Beaglebone?